# How to select every second element within jquery nextUntil?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to select every second element after using .nextUntil() method of jquery. How can i select every second element after the selector element?

I already tried using `.nextUntil(".headerRow", "tr:odd")` as well as `.nextUntil(".headerRow", "tr:nth-child(odd)")`

This is my line of code which i want to get working:

`$('.headerRow').nextUntil(".headerRow", "tr:nth-child(odd)").css("background-color", "rgb(240,240,240)");`

It selects every second `tr`... however it selects the rows based on the whole table instead of the last `.headerRow`

It looks like:

```
<tr> - (not selected)
<tr> - (not selected)
<tr> - (not selected)
<tr class="headerRow"> - (not selected)
<tr> - (selected)
<tr> - (not selected)
<tr class="headerRow"> - (not selected)
<tr> - (not selected) <----- should be selected
<tr> - (selected) <------ shouldn't be selected
<tr> - (not selected) <----- should be selected
<tr class="headerRow"> - (not selected)
<tr> - (selected)
<tr> - (not selected)
...
```

It should start selecting the `<tr>` like this:

```
<tr> - (not selected, ok)
<tr> - (not selected, ok)
<tr> - (not selected, ok)
<tr class="headerRow"> - (not selected)
<tr> - (selected)
<tr> - (not selected)
<tr class="headerRow"> - (not selected)
<tr> - (selected)
<tr> - (not selected)
<tr> - (selected)
<tr class="headerRow"> - (not selected)
<tr> - (selected)
<tr> - (not selected)
...
```

How can i fix this?

EDIT: Table is generated like this:

```
<table id="bomTable" class="hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${list.listItems}" var="item">
        <tr <c:if test="${item.rowType == 'HEADLINE'}">class="headerRow"</c:if>>
            <td>${item.materialNumber}</td>
            <td>${item.materialDescription}</td>
            <td>${item.quantity}</td>
            <td>${item.unit}</td>
         </tr>
     </c:forEach>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `nextUntil()` would use the "filter" parameter based on the entire list of `<tr>`, in fact the "selected" elements are the odd ones (except for the `headerRow` ones, because of the "until" function. Maybe isomething more about "how" you generate that list could be of help and allow for a different approach to the problem

Comment: I've added how i generate the table. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly not achievable by just using `:odd, :even` since odds and evens are references to their *absolute* order.

Therefore you first need to **group** - before applying odds and evens - which in return will become *relative* for that group.
Here is one example by using `.each()`:

```js
$('.headerRow').each(function() {
   $(this).nextUntil('.headerRow', 'tr:even').css('background', 'red');
});
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>no</td></tr>
<tr><td>no</td></tr>
<tr><td>no</td></tr>
<tr class="headerRow"><td>---HR no---</td></tr>
<tr><td>sel</td></tr>
<tr><td>no</td></tr>
<tr class="headerRow"><td>---HR no---</td></tr>
<tr><td>sel</td></tr>
<tr><td>no</td></tr>
<tr><td>sel</td></tr>
<tr><td>no</td></tr>
<tr><td>sel</td></tr>
<tr class="headerRow"><td>---HR no---</td></tr>
<tr class="headerRow"><td>---HR no---</td></tr>
<tr class="headerRow"><td>---HR no---</td></tr>
<tr class="headerRow"><td>---HR no---</td></tr>
<tr><td>sel</td></tr>
<tr><td>no</td></tr>
</table>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

`$(this).nextUntil('.headerRow')`, is our iterable group.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what i needed. Also pretty simple, too.